# Apply checkin policy so that contributors have to link to work items in TFS Service

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

How can I apply a checkin policy so that contributors have to link to work items in TFS Service?

I want it so that no contributor can checkin in TFS service (tfs.visualstudio.com) without linking to a work item.

Answer (score 7):

In VS2010 or VS2012

Open -> "Team Explorer".
Select your "Team Project".
Right Click -> "Team Project Settings" -> "Source Control".
Select the "Check-in Policy" Tab.
Click "Add..."
Select "WorkItem".

In visual studio for the policy to take effect all client machines need to have TFS power tools installed. [TFS POwer tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f)

As of now, there is no way of enforcing it completely (Atleast I havent found one). Users always have the option of overriding the policy as mentioned [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245460%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Overriding the policies are by design in TFS. But what you can do is:

Vs2010 - > Team -> Alerts Explorer -> New Alert -> Checkin Alerts -> and add "Check-in to a specific folder with policy overridden". Mention your email for this alert. This will let you know which all developers are overriding the policy and you can contact them.

Answer (score 0):

As Isaiah4110 said, there is no default rule to enfoce linking workitems before checking.
But I think you can try to write your own custom checkin rules.
You can refer it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/03/31/how-to-implement-package-and-deploy-custom-check-in-policy-for-tfs-2010.aspx).