# How to set TFS Work item is mandatory during Checkin?

Tags: tfs, checkin, workitem

I need to enforce policy to my developers to associate one or more Workitems during checkin. Can someone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TFS Service: How to apply checkin policy so that contributors have to link to work items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18098568/tfs-service-how-to-apply-checkin-policy-so-that-contributors-have-to-link-to-wo)

Comment: The answer below is the closest you can get to ensure a workitem is associated to a check-in. You cannot make it mandatory as users can always "OVERRIDE" it.

Answer (score 4):

You find the solution here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg475890(v=vs.100).aspx

Under the point "Add Check-in policies"

Its called "Work Item Policy".

Cheers